# MS Access Complicated Order By

Tags: sql, ms-access

For an invoicing app I'm working on my PHB has decided that the parts sold listed on the invoice need to go in a very unique order.  I would like to accomplish this with a single sql statement if possible.

Essentially the order needs to be as such

1. The most expensive part (but only if there is another part listed at $0)
2. All parts listed at $0
3. All other parts (or all parts) listed by order of part_id
4. All parts with a part_id of ("MISC-30","MISC-31","TEMP")
5. All parts with a negative qty [returns]

There is also a jumble of comments that will need to be added but That will have to be handled by the code

So far I have:

```
SELECT * 
FROM order_part 
WHERE ordid = 1234 
ORDER BY qty > 0, part_id NOT IN("MISC-30","MISC-31","TEMP"), part_id
```

However I cannot figure out how to incorporate the first 2 rules

Comment: That's the part with the most expensive price or do you factor in quantity?

Comment: A couple of points: 1) SELECT * is bad practice; 2) it is good practice to 'expose' the sort order in the SELECT clause; in SQL you would use the correlation name, rather than the full expression, in the ORDER BY clause but sadly Access Database Engine SQL is not really SQL, though you can get around this with a subquery, which sadly the Access Database Engine does not optimize well :(

Comment: it was a pseudo example, the actual query is quite a bit longer.

Comment: @onedaywhen: There is no problem in Jet/ACE SQL with ORDER BY on expressions. No, you can't use the alias from your SELECT, but you can use the expression itself -- it doesn't require a subquery just to sort by an expression. And please posting BS like "is not really SQL" -- there are lots of dialects of SQL and varying levels of support for different aspects of the standard. You look like an idiot when you make petty little jabs like that.

Comment: @David W. Fenton: don't you think it is a little daft that if you want to sort on an expression you used in the SELECT clause you have to repeat the whole expression in the ORDER BY clause? You should know that code repetition is a maintenance nightmare e.g. bugs because someone changed the expression in the SELECT clause but not the ORDER BY clause. Do you have a citation to reassure me that the optimizer will 'see' both expressions as being the same?

Comment: ...the SQL-92 Standard allows (actually, requires) you to use the column correlation name. It is easy to demonstrate that Access Database Engine SQL is not real SQL:  it does not conform to entry level SQL-92. Q.E.D.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you've had to give up being messing long ago on this project ;)

```
Select * 
    , IIF(((Select Count(*) from order_part 
        where orderid = 1234 and price = 0))=0 
           and price = ((select max(price) from       
               order_part where orderid = 1234
           and qty >0 and part_id not in(("MISC-30","MISC-31","TEMP") 
          )), 1
    , IIf(price = 0, 2
    , IIf(part_id IN("MISC-30","MISC-31","TEMP"), 4
    , IIf(qty < 0, 5
    , 3)))) AS Part_Sort
from order_part
Order By Part Sort, part_id
```

Really wish Access had case statement. But you can build these nested IIf's and provide a sorting number based on your logic. The final "ELSE" part is the #3 since just sorting by the part ID is the third choice/ doesn't fall under these other categories. Sorry, I know the parenthesis are wrong.

Comment: Looks like a slight variation of this is going to work.  thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you mean you want to have a **single recordset** i.e. output from your SQL that can be processed by your invoicing App?

Have you thought of the folling -- Its not pretty but it might work.

```
Select * From
(
    Select 1 as MyOrder .... rest of criteria 1
    Union
    Select 2 as MyOrder .... rest of criteria 2
    Union
    Select 3 as MyOrder .... rest of criteria 3
    Union
    Select 4 as MyOrder .... rest of criteria 4
    Union
    Select 5 as MyOrder .... rest of criteria 5
)
Order by MyOrder
```

Comment: That could work but how do i get it to determine if there is any parts listed at $0

Comment: Query #1 would have #2 as part of its where clause.

Answer (score 1):

If it's not possible to do this with one select statement, I would write 5 queries that each get the parts of this end query you need with no intersections.  Then add a `SortBy` integer value to each query and union them together (sorting by the `SortBy` value).

I've done this in SQL Server and I'm guessing this is possible in Access...

Answer (score 1):

Even if this is possible with a single query, I think you owe it to yourself and future developers to make individual queries and join the results together some other way.

The only exception to this is if performance is 100% completely critical and you need to save every microsecond.

But as a developer and manager I'd rather see maintainable code that a junior team member can figure out than some uber-messy SQL statement.

Comment: WEll i'm the only developer and trust me its already a mess with the commenting rules. but anyway we need to print out about 500 of these at a time.  the most i can do in the sql the better. 

I might end up doing it using a sub query but i dont know yet

Comment: Also I DO have an 18 page document describing how the orders need to be formatted including the order of the items and what comments need to accompany them

Comment: UNION ALL will be pretty fast, though, of course, sorting on the result won't use the underlying indexes.

Answer (score -1):

My advice: have the guy that makes you waste your precious time doing such dummy things fired! He must be a slave driver or something? If you can't have him fired, leave the company.

Comment: +1 While the OP has no power to fire his boss, the principle is correct -- the PHB should pay for this kind of stupidity in terms of a reprimand from his superior, whoever that is. Dunno how a lowly programmer conveys the information to someone he doesn't report to, but that's what would happen in an ideal world.