# Order rows according to which condition is met?

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-order-by

I have a pretty simple question: Is it possible to order the rows retrieved according to the which condition is met?
For example, I have a table of people, and I want to retrieve all people whose names begin with an "I", or end with an "ster", or contain "lo", ordered according to which condition of these is met. First the rows that match the first condition, then the rows that match the second, and so on. (**Without duplicated:** if a row meets the first condition, it shouldn't show again for the second condition)

**Edit:**
I work with Visual C#, and I manage the DB with MS Access. (The file format is .mdb, if that matters)

Thank you =)

Comment: Not possible through standard sql. You could do it programmatically though if you retrieve your result set into Java, C#, etc

Comment: No, it's entirely possible in standard SQL.  It's just a little involved depending on some of the details.

Comment: The real problem is that Access supports a smaller subset of standard SQL than the bigger DBMS's (like SQL Server, Oracle, DB2, etc.) and so may not support all of the different ways to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this ought to work:

```
SELECT * FROM people
ORDER BY
  CASE WHEN name LIKE "I%" THEN 0
    WHEN name LIKE "%ster" THEN 1
    WHEN name LIKE "%lo%" THEN 2
    ELSE 3
  END ASC;
```

In Access you may have to resort to nested `IIF()`s though:

```
ORDER BY
  IIF( name LIKE "I%",     0,
  IIF( name LIKE "%ster%", 1,
  IIF( name LIKE "%lo%",   2,
    3
  ) ) ) ASC
```

Answer (score 7):

Generally speaking, you can put a case statement in your `order by`.

This would work in SQL Server, for example:

```
order by (case when myCol like 'I%' then 1 when myCol like '%ster' then 2 when myCol like '%lo%' then 3 end)
```

<strike>Which DBMS are you using?</strike>

**UPDATE**

For MS-ACCESS, you could use the `IIF` statement as shown in this answer:

[ms-access-complicated-order-by](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1676843/880904)

Based upon that, you probably want something along the lines of:

```
SELECT *
FROM people
WHERE [name] Like "I*" Or [name] Like "*ster" Or [name] Like "*lo*"
ORDER BY IIf([name] Like "I*", 1, IIf([name] Like "*ster", 2, IIf([name] Like "*lo*", 3, 4)));
```

Comment: @Itamar Marom, please let me know if this works and please edit the final Access query here if the syntax is slightly off (unfortunately I can't check it right now).

Answer (score 2):

I gave this a shot with Postgres, but I would assume you could use a similar technique with other DBs.  I would create a column for each condition which returns a Boolean expression of whether the condition is met.  Then, order by that column:

```
select
   substr(Name, 1, 1) = 'I' as StartsWithI,
   Name like '%ster' as EndsWithSter
from MyTable
order by StartsWithI desc, EndsWithSter desc
```

**UPDATE:**

The `ms-access` tag was added after I posted this answer, but I'll leave it up in case it helps anyone.

Answer (score 1):

The `Switch` function is much more readable than a bunch of nested `IIf` statements:

```
SELECT * FROM [People]
WHERE [Name] Like "I*"
   OR [Name] Like "*ster"
   OR [Name] Like "*lo*"
ORDER BY Switch([Name] Like "I*", 1,
                [Name] Like "*ster", 2,
                True, 3)
```

`Switch` is used by passing argument pairs of *conditional* : *result*.  Argument 1 is evaluated and if true the function returns argument 2.  If arg 1 is false, then arg 3 is evaluated, etc.

Note the use of `True` as the penultimate argument which acts like a `CASE ELSE`.

Be aware that depending on the context, you may need to convert `*` to `%`.  See [Why does LIKE behave differently when being called from VB6 app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/690731/ms-access-query-why-does-like-behave-differently-when-being-called-from-vb6-app) for more info.